# Apache .htaccess rewrite rule causing an invalid host name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I'm trying to forward all requests from domain1.com to domain2.com, **without redirect** using mod_proxy and mod_rewrite. My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/$1 [L,P]
```

Actually this isn't working because it produces **an invalid host**. The target site `domain2.com` complains about **invalid host**, that it seems to be the following:

```
domain1.com, domain1.com
```

Yes, with comma. Any idea is much appreciated.

If I dump the server variables i get `domain1.com, domain1.com` as **SERVER_NAME** and **HTTP_HOST**.

**EDIT:** I solved looking at the [source code doing the check](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/v2.8.19/Request.php#L1210).

AFIK it seems **pretty normal to double the host value**. Why? Because setting the IP of the proxy as trusted proxy the magic happens: the host **get splitted by ','** and the last will be used as host, that is domain1.com. It works.

Comment: Does it work when you replace `P` with `R` flag?

Comment: @anubhava yes, it works with a 301 redirect to the correct page. I think because the host isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sending requests from one domain to another is a perfect example for `ProxyPass`.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://domain2.com
ProxyPassReverse / http://domain2.com
```

This requires the modules `proxy` and `proxy_http`, but should solve your problem.

Comment: I'll try this later, but I'd like to know why my first example doesn't... that is why host is duplicate, any clue?

Comment: I can't think of a way to get `domain1.com, domain1.com` ^^ Where do you see that? Some log entry?

Comment: Yes, in my log. If you are familiar with PHP, here is the check: https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/v2.8.19/Request.php#L1210 and my log show "domain1, domain1" as host.

Comment: I'm no PHP-expert, but know it well enough to understand that^^ pretty confusing though....myb your code went wrong somewhere else? I mean, that doesn't normally happen by accident :D

Comment: The code goes wrong in that very line: if you debug the host variable you'll get the following string: `domain1, domain1` which of course is completly wrong (it should be `domain1`). It seems apache is proxing the request sending a wrong host.

Comment: But I'm not sure if Apache can even create a host-string like `domain1.com, domain1.com` And from the lines posted it doesn't happen there. Did it ever work and stopped after a specific change?

Comment: I created the `.htaccess` yesterday, so it never worked. Your `.htaccess` doesn't work too, it gives me an **Internal Server Error**.

Comment: 500 - internal server error almost always points to another underlying problem that just wasn't handled correctly, like trying to serve a 404-page and failig becuase there is none...can you turn up your `LogLevel` to `info` (at least), restart and post what the log says regarding this 500 error? If you want, answer in chat

Comment: Thanks for helping, I solved. It turns out that it's the normal behaviour.